# App\XyzModel not found error in Laravel 7x

Tags: php, laravel-7

When I was trying to fetch the records from the database I got the following error

---

**App\XyzModel Class not found**

---

All I did is:

- Deleted the XyzModel.php file from app\providers
- Then I created a new Model with the command `php artisan make:model XyzModel` and tried to run the same previous code snippet and it was successfully fetching the records

(**Note**: If you change the directory or name of the Model and it's showing the same error follow the above mention steps)

Creating a new Model:

```
php artisan make:model XyzModel
```

Comment: `xyzModel` or `XyzModel`? How do you `use` that model?

Comment: It's just an example you can use any Model name whichever you want to define it.

Comment: You deleted your model from app\providers (what is a model doing there in the first place?)  and then created a new model at app\XyzModel. That is a different namespace. Also is it xyzModel or xyzModel? Try to make your question more clear and show more code ...

Comment: Point is, `xyzModel` is not `XyzModel`. Can you show your actual code/controller ([edit] your question) of where that error occurs instead of fictional model names, how's that gonna help?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try `composer dump-autoload` and check how did you import this model.